# Drawing cubes with stacked matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to understand some parts of OpenGL. I have to create a robot, which is made from a few part. At start I want to draw 3 cubes in a row. At first I want to draw a cube in the middle, and after that the rest two.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

```
void drawScene(GLFWwindow* window) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    mat4 P=perspective(50.0f*PI/180.0f,aspect,1.0f,50.0f);
    mat4 V=lookAt(
                  vec3(0.0f,0.0f,-15.0f),
                  vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),
                  vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(value_ptr(P));
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    mat4 M=mat4(1.0f);
    glLoadMatrixf(value_ptr(V*M));

    glPushMatrix();                         //create matrix 1 on the top
    Models::cube.drawSolid();               //draw cube on 0,0,0 coords
    glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0);            //apply translation to matrix 1
    Models::cube.drawSolid();               //draw cube on 3,0,0 coords
    glPopMatrix();                          
    glRotatef(180*PI/180, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Models::cube.drawSolid();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

And another example which is giving me the same wrong results:

```
void drawScene(GLFWwindow* window) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    mat4 P=perspective(50.0f*PI/180.0f,aspect,1.0f,50.0f);
    mat4 V=lookAt(
                  vec3(0.0f,0.0f,-15.0f),
                  vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),
                  vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(value_ptr(P));
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    mat4 M=mat4(1.0f);
    glLoadMatrixf(value_ptr(V*M));

    glPushMatrix(); //Matrix 1 on the top
    glPushMatrix(); //Matrix 2 on the top
    Models::cube.drawSolid(); //Draw cube on matrix 2
    glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Apply translation on matrix 2
    glPushMatrix(); //Matrix 3 on the top
    Models::cube.drawSolid(); //Draw cube on matrix 3
    glPopMatrix(); //Matrix 2 on the top
    glPopMatrix(); //Matrix 1 on the top
    glRotatef(180*PI/180, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Apply translation on matrix 1
    glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Apply translation on matrix 1
    Models::cube.drawSolid(); //Draw cube on matrix 1

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

In both cases I have to translate last cube for `6.0` instead of `3.0`. I dont really understand why. It seems to me that after backing to matrix 1 I apply effect on them.

To be clear, I want to do something like this:

```
Draw Cube in 0,0,0
    []
go to 3,0,0 
Draw Cube
    []  []
Go back to 0,0,0
Rotate in 180 degrees
Go to -3,0,0
Draw Cube   
[]  []  []
```

Comment: You may want to simplify your matrix operations and avoid redundant changes. e.g *glPushMatrix(); //Matrix 1 on the top
    glPushMatrix(); //Matrix 2 on the top* is not doing anything different. Also if you want to just translate then do *glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0);* and then render object instead of doing push and pop. Keep in mind they are costly.

Comment: This is the old fixed pipeline opengl, rather learn opengl 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to draw a cube in the center, a second cube translated to the right and a third cube translated to the left (along the X-axis).
This can be done in different ways:

You can draw the cube in the center, go **one step to the right** and draw the next cube and finally go **two steps to the left** an draw the third cube:

```
float step = 3.0f;

Models::cube.drawSolid();
glTranslatef( 1.0f * step, 0.0f, 0.0f );
Models::cube.drawSolid();
glTranslatef( -2.0f * step, 0.0f, 0.0f );
Models::cube.drawSolid();
```

You can draw the cube in the center and save (**push**) the model matirx, go **one step to the right** and draw the next cube and finally restore (**pop**) the model matrix, go **one steps to the left** an draw the third cube:

```
glPushMatrix();  
Models::cube.drawSolid();
glTranslatef( 1.0f * step, 0.0f, 0.0f );
Models::cube.drawSolid();
glPopMatrix();                          
glTranslatef( -1.0f * step, 0.0f, 0.0f );
Models::cube.drawSolid();
```

Finally what you desided to do.
Draw the cube in the center and save (**push**) the model matirx, go **one step to the right** and draw the next cube and finally restore (**pop**) the model matrix, **turn around 180° degrees**, go **one steps to the right** an draw the third cube. But you have to rotate around the up vector, which is (0, 1, 0) in your case, and not around the X-axis:

[image]

```
glPushMatrix();  
Models::cube.drawSolid();
glTranslatef( 1.0f * step, 0.0f, 0.0f );
Models::cube.drawSolid();
glPopMatrix();                          
glRotatef( 180*PI/180, 0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f ); // rotate around the up vector
glTranslatef( 1.0f * step, 0.0f, 0.0f );
Models::cube.drawSolid();
```

By the way, in your 2nd example you push 3 matrices onto the stack, but you pop only 2 matrices. Each matrix which is put on the stack should also be taken down again. This means the number of `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`should always be equal. Else you would either stack up without an end, or you would try to take something from the empty stack.